# How to enable Multi-Level undo/redo in mshtml & c#

Tags: c#, winforms, mshtml, undo-redo

I have a System.Windows.Forms.Webbrowser control hosted in a Winforms app and am loading up a html document that has various elements with the contentEditable attribute set to true.  How do I enable multi-level undo and redo for the document?

TIA.

MB

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would think you can apply the library [DejaVu](http://dejavu.codeplex.com/) found in codeplex.

here is the [blog link](http://dejavu-codeplex.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Undo/Redo is built in 
here's the control i had used earlier
http://www.itwriting.com/htmleditor/